# Horizontal submenu background filling viewport width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the background of the submenu on this navigation menu to fill the width of the view port.

Here is my example: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Aa58oKz6jR).

I would also like the submenu to continue to display under the parent menu item.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed styles for `.activeItem` and introduced styles for `.activeItem:before` and `.activeItem:after`.

`.activeItem:before` draws arrow and `.activeItem:after` draws blue background.

I removed backgound in `.dropdown-menu` because now it's not needed.

And also I wrapped whole menu in `.wrapper`.

It's not the most elegant code, but I have no better idea.

See here http://www.bootply.com/yiEGyUDYUF

You still need to work on mobile version.

Comment: That did it. That works exactly how I was trying to get it to work.  Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the `vh` property to specify a width relative to the viewport:

ex: `width: 100vh`